# Joomla 3 - Different article order on different pages

Tags: html, joomla, article, joomla3.4

I am using Joomla 3.4.4 and I am displaying multiple articles by Category Blog menu item. I have 3 of these menu items and I need them to display the same articles, but each in different specific order.

Do you have any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: All the articles you want to display are in the same Category ?    
You have created 3 menu items, each one should display this group of article in different order ? What are the orders needed ?

Comment: Yes, they are all in the same category. Each link is for different kind of customer and I need to order the articles (services) based on what is the priority for the customer (I will manually specify the priority)

Comment: So, you want custom orders, not sorting by the title or creation date of the article for example ? The order would be a sort but an order specified manually by an admin ?

Comment: Where is the priority stored?

Comment: @Michel yes, custom orders.

Comment: @Elin Nowhere right now, because I'm not sure where to store it

Comment: Is this a dynamic list (is it changing all the time) or  static (not changing much) for each group?

Comment: @Elin static, it won't change much

Comment: What I would do is to make a module rather than use a component.  In the module make three fields and enter the article ids in order for the different groups.  Then check the group of the user, (if the articles are different do the different queries), and then  display using the order stored with the module for that specific group.  IT will take a little bit of coding and using an array sort.

Comment: @Elin yea, I think will do something like that, thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

As I know, in Joomla (<= 3.4), the custom ordering of articles is set globally, beyond of categories. In the database, we can see that the `content` table (articles) contains independent `catid` and `ordering` fields, and there is no trace of a table that could implement an association with fields like : `catid | contenid | ordering`

Maybe :

- it's an upcoming feature : search in
  https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms
- a component/plugin allows this
  : check http://extensions.joomla.org

If not, you should consider developing an extension adding order per category with a content-categories-ordering association table... Maybe with an extension like [Fabrik](http://fabrikar.com/) you could manage this easier, without having to develop a full Joomla extension.

Comment: I think I will make my own module or something for it, beacouse I could not find anything that would make it possible

Comment: You could develop a content type component allowing to choose order of articles of a categories in different lists. It would work on a association table like articles_categories  as I mentionned in my answer.
In the admin the component it would be possible to create lists of articles, and then the user could manage orders of articles for each different list; on the front-end you display these sets in menu items showing instances of this component.